# Adobe eats hospitalised hedgehogs: Reader 2017 reports PDFs as damaged

Tags: beamer, graphics, pdf, viewers, acrobat

I create slides for teaching on a GNU/Linux machine and test in Okular. I then transfer the files to university storage so that I can use them in class. This has been working well. However, today, Adobe Reader 2017 reported 2 of the 3 PDFs as damaged. In both cases, the slides displayed fine except that all images of hospitalised hedgehogs were missing. The space was there, but no hedgehog. All other images displayed fine. All text displayed fine.

I just re-transferred the 'damaged' PDFs to my laptop and the files are identical to those I uploaded. I also double-checked that the originals  include the hopsitalised hedgehog everywhere they should. Okular shows everything is fine.

[Adobe Reader XI reports corrupted PDF for pdfTeX compiled combination beamer + overlay + textblock + includgraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432050/adobe-reader-xi-reports-corrupted-pdf-for-pdftex-compiled-combination-beamer-o) seems related, but it is difficult to be sure and the comments say the problem can't be reproduced.

The image causing the problem for me is included as PDF. But the slides also use a picture of a cat, also included as PDF, and not a problem.

If I read the content of the PDF as text, I can see the file path for the PDF images. (I was surprised by this - I didn't realise the original file path would be included.)

The only two differences I can see in the treatment of the two images is that

1. the hedgehog is included multiple times at different sizes, whereas the cat image is included only once at a single size;
2. the hedgehog is saved into a box at one of the sizes and used as a 'logo' on various slides, whereas the cat is not.

However, I am not sure how to tell whether either, both or neither of these is the problem or not.

Creating an MWE is tricky because I have no way of knowing when the problem has gone away, since I only use Windows in the classrooms I teach in and don't have it available otherwise. (If necessary, I can use a lab computer for testing, but that's a pain.)

Basically, a schematic of my code would look like this:

```
\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{hedgehog}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[width=.225\textwidth]{hedgehog}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cat}
\end{frame}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

The logo code I'm using looks like this

```
\newsavebox{\hhl}
\sbox{\hhl}{%
        \includegraphics[scale=.5]{hedgehogs/hedgehoghospital}}
\newcommand*\hhllogo{%
  \logo{\usebox{\hhl}}% followed by code to create an attribution at the bottom of slides
}
\newcommand*\nologo{%
  \logo{}% followed by code to clear the attribution from the bottom of slides
}
\hhllogo
```

Would either the inclusion of a PDF image at multiple sizes or the placement of the PDF using Beamer's `\logo{}` be expected to create issues for Adobe Reader 2017? I should note that this code worked fine with earlier versions of Reader, as I've not had this problem before and these slides are virtually unchanged from previous years.

If the answer to the above is 'No', how can I best debug this in order to figure out what I need to avoid to get things working correctly?

Comment: same problems with SumatraPDF or Foxit Reader?

Comment: Is it possible to take an example of damaged (hedgehog) PDF file from somewhere to analyse?

Comment: I’ve had stray problems displaying Beamer PDF files on the Windows computers in classrooms; encrypting the PDF with [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) seems to prevent that in many cases, for reasons I don’t understand.  BTW, here be [hedgehogs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?x-yt-ts=1421914688&feature=player_embedded&x-yt-cl=84503534&v=57BTS-W_2QI).

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Do you mind if it isn't minimal? I'm happy to post an example now, but it would just be one of the PDFs I know is problematic.

Comment: @Thérèse Encrypting it? You man you put a password on it? And then enter the password to show it?

Comment: No, just a password that prevents altering the PDF.  No password needed to open it. Use like this: `qpdf --encrypt "" mypassword 128 --accessibility=y --extract=n --print=full --modify=none --cleartext-metadata --use-aes=y -- original-file.pdf encrypted-version.pdf`

Comment: @Thérèse Maybe that should be an answer? I wouldn't be inclined to accept it as it is clearly a workaround, but it deserves an upvote. (Even if it turns out not to work for me.)

Comment: https://cfrees.files.wordpress.com/2018/06/5-kant4-fhei-p.pdf @PrzemysławScherwentke

Comment: @naphaneal I have no way to test either of those. I don't have a Windows machine to play with.

Comment: @cfr I have only checked that it is viewer-dependent. Chrome and Sumatra have no problems, but other viewers I have checked -- have.

Comment: Could you make the offending PDF (the included graphics) available for download please, perhaps it can be repaired with `pdftk`.

Comment: I checked the provided PDF with Foxit Reader, Sumatra, Adobe and PDF-Xchange. out of these four only Adobe complained about a broken PDF. the rest notified about interactive fields, with the exception of Sumatra, which did not show the field. Adobe also did not show any logo or hedgehog. I also checked with several browser plugins. sofar all notified for the interactive fields, but presented all contents.

Comment: *If I read the content of the PDF as text, I can see the file path for the PDF images. (I was surprised by this - I didn't realise the original file path would be included.)* This minor aspect has been discussed before -- further reading: [Is the filename of an image preserved in the final PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154096/28808)

Comment: It fails to display in Adobe Reader X on Win7 for me, sugesting that Adobe haven't changed anything for a while (BTW I'm just down the road from you)

Comment: @AlexG I can't legally do that. In any case, it is really not necessary as I also have a PNG version.

Comment: @ChrisH There was no problem 2 years ago in Adobe. However, what that means is just that there was no problem in whatever version of Reader was installed on university pool room machines 2 years ago. That may or may not have been the version of Reader current at the time.

Comment: @cfr that's what's strange. I rarely use lecture theatre /pool machines as a postdoc but my machine is a CU standard win7 configuration. I think Adobe have patched reader X and maybe one of those patches made it more fussy. That wouldn't be surprising as security patches could well address malformed input

Comment: @ChrisH When you said 'up the road', I had no idea you meant quite so literally :). There are at least 2 versions of Adobe Reader on networked machines. Some pool room machines have copies of both; others have only one or other. The interfaces are very different. So you may very well have a network image and still have the older version of the reader. Or, as you say, it could be a difference of patches. My guess is that my slides would work OK in some pool rooms, which don't have the new version of the reader installed.

Comment: @ChrisH If you can fill in the form boxes in my slides and save the content, you have the new version of the viewer; if you can fill in the boxes but cannot save the content, you have the old version.

Comment: @cfr I can fill in but not save; it's 10.1.16.  But  no hedgehogs :(. So I suspect that the major version isn't sufficient to determine whether it works, however Reader X went out of support in 2015.  At least you have a solution to the immediate problem that doesn't seem to rely on INSRV being consistent. (I work at the same place as cfr, so was intrigued by the problem and thought I might be in a position to do some useful testing)

Comment: @ChrisH Well, this was probably last tested in summer 2016. So, given update times, it may well have been an earlier version of Acrobat. And you're right, major version obviously isn't enough. Thanks for the testing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The PDF file has many errors.

Output of `ps2pdf` (ghostscript):

```
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Form stream has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many q's)
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Recursive XObject detected, ignoring "Fm1", object number 51
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Recursive XObject detected, ignoring "Im8", object number 11
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Recursive XObject detected, ignoring "Fm3", object number 55
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: Recursive XObject detected, ignoring "Fm3", object number 55
[...]
```

Evince reports:

```
 Error (3014): Incorrect number of arguments in 'sc' command
```

Xpdf reports the same error:

```
Syntax Error (2966): Incorrect number of arguments in 'sc' command
```

The error (sc) seems to be present in `hedgehoghospital.pdf`. It is s low-resolution bitmap image with a PDF wrapper.

The offending code:

```pdf
stream
q Q q 0 0 139 142 re W n 0 sc /Gs1 gs 0 0 139 142 re f /Perceptual
ri /Gs2 gs q 139 0 0 142 0 0 cm /Im1 Do Q Q
endstream
```

I have not found the corresponding `cs` operator that defines the color space. Maybe, the default is `/DeviceRGB` with *three* parameters and `0 sc` only uses one parameter.

Workarounds:

- Maybe, you can find/generate a better version of `hedgehoghospital.pdf`,
  preferable a vector version.
- Use of the bitmap data (PNG) without PDF wrapper:

The program `pdfimages` can be used to extract the bitmap data.
Since, I do not have `hedgehoghospital.pdf`, I have used the third page
(`pdftk 5-kant4-fhei-p.pdf cat 3 output 3.pdf uncompress`).

```
pdfimages `hedgehoghospital.pdf` h
```

This generates:

- `h-0000.ppm`, the image data
- `h-0001.ppm`, the transparency mask

Next, the image mask needs to be saved in grayscale format:

```
ppmtopgm <h-0001.ppm > h-0001.pgm
```

Then both images can be composed to the PNG file:

```
pnmtopng -alpha=333-0001.pgm <333-0000.ppm >hedgehog.png
```

Then, `hedgehog.png` can be used instead of `hedgehog.pdf`:

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. I also have a PNG, so I think I can just delete the PDF and force use of the PNG. Has Adobe's viewer got a lot fussier? I've used the same images in these slides for ages and I've never had the hedgehog disappear before. I suspect the cat PDF is also bitmap, but it doesn't mind that?

Comment: The wrapper for the cat does not use `sc`.

Comment: I guess that's not small-caps in this context?

Comment: @cfr `sc` refers to the PDF operator that causes the trouble in the hedgehog case.

Answer (score 7):

For reasons which were never clear, I’ve also had problems displaying some Beamer PDF files with the Windows computers in classrooms, files created on my GNU/Linux box. In my experience, encrypting the PDF with [qpdf](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) seems to prevent that in many cases, and possibly it will work for you as well.

I don’t understand exactly how ‘qpdf’ helps, but its manual says, ‘QPDF does structural, content-preserving transformations on PDF files. It could have been called something like pdf-to-pdf.’ It allows for linearization, encryption, some repairs, etc.

The manual is on the long side, so here’s a quick start: you can encrypt a file with

```
qpdf --encrypt "" mypassword 128 --accessibility=y --extract=n --print=full --modify=none --cleartext-metadata --use-aes=y -- original-file.pdf encrypted-version.pdf
```